# How to run DBT in airflow without copying our repo

Tags: airflow, dbt

We use airflow to orchestrate our workflows, and dbt with bigquery for our daily transformations in BigQuery. We have two separate git repos, one for our dbt project and a separate one for airflow.

It seems the simplest approach to scheduling our daily `run dbt` seems to be a `BashOperator` in airflow. However, to schedule DBT to run with Airflow, it seems like our entire DBT project would need to be nested inside of our Airflow project, that way we can point to it for our `dbt run` bash command?

Is it possible to trigger our `dbt run` and `dbt test` without moving our DBT directory inside of our Airflow directory? With the [airflow-dbt package](https://github.com/gocardless/airflow-dbt),  for the `dir` in the `default_args`, maybe it is possible to point to the gibhub link for the DBT project here?

Comment: When you use(ed) airflow-dbt package, how do you manage the service account key? Did you keep in GCS bucket?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My advice would be to leave your dbt and airflow codebases separated.
There is indeed a better way:

1. dockerise your dbt project in a simple python-based image where you COPY the codebase
2. push that to DockerHub or ECR or any other docker repository that you are using
3. use the [`DockerOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html) in your airflow DAG to run that docker image with your dbt code

I'm assuming that you use the airflow LocalExecutor here and that you want to execute your `dbt run` workload on the server where airflow is running. If that's not the case and that you have access to a Kubernetes cluster, I would suggest instead to use the `KubernetesPodOperator`.

Comment: I heavily second this. I think this has become the de facto community standard for self-hosted dbt scheduling.

Comment: This is great, knew there had to be a better way than combining codebases. I will definitely use this approach.

Comment: Awesome approach, I will try this.

Comment: Hi @louis_guitton, I have more questions for you regarding your implementation with the Docker Operator. I have included it as a separate question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65464756/running-dbt-within-airflow-through-the-docker-operator) if you want to share more insights about your experience using that approach = )

Comment: Hey 1 more question , how do you mange the service account ? Do you keep in image?

Answer (score 3):

Accepted the other answer based on the consensus via upvotes and the supporting comment, however this is a 2nd option we're currently using:

- `dbt` and `airflow` repos / directories are next to each other.
- in our airflow's `docker-compose.yml`, we've added our DBT directory as a volume so that airflow has access to it.
- in our airflow's `Dockerfile`, install DBT and copy our `dbt` code.
- use `BashOperator` to `run dbt` and `test dbt`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re on GCP another option that is completely serverless is to run dbt with cloud build instead of airflow. You can also add workflows to that if you want more orchestration. If you want a detailed description there’s a post describing it. https://robertsahlin.com/serverless-dbt-on-google-cloud-platform/