# Running DBT within Airflow through the Docker Operator

Tags: docker, airflow, dbt

Building my question on [How to run DBT in airflow without copying our repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890144/how-to-run-dbt-in-airflow-without-copying-our-repo), I am currently running airflow and syncing the dags via git. I am considering different option to include DBT within my workflow. One suggestion by [louis_guitton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3823815/louis-guitton) is to Dockerize the DBT project, and run it in Airflow via the [Docker Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html).

I have no prior experience using the Docker Operator in Airflow or generally DBT. I am wondering if anyone has tried or can provide some insights about their experience incorporating that workflow, my main questions are:

1. Should DBT as a whole project be run as one Docker container, or is it broken down? (for example: are tests ran as a separate container from dbt tasks?)
2. Are logs and the UI from DBT accessible and/or still useful when run via the Docker Operator?
3. How would partial pipelines be run? (example: wanting to run only a part of the pipeline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging by your questions, you would benefit from trying to dockerise dbt on its own, independently from airflow. A lot of your questions would disappear. But here are my answers anyway.

1. > Should DBT as a whole project be run as one Docker container, or is it broken down? (for example: are tests ran as a separate container from dbt tasks?)

I suggest you build one docker image for the entire project. The docker image can be based on the python image since dbt is a python CLI tool. You then use the CMD arguments of the docker image to run any dbt command you would run outside docker.
Please remember the syntax of `docker run` (which has nothing to do with dbt): you can specify any COMMAND you wand to run at invocation time

```sh
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Also, the first hit on Google for "docker dbt" is [this dockerfile](https://github.com/davidgasquez/dbt-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) that can get you started

2. > Are logs and the UI from DBT accessible and/or still useful when run via the Docker Operator?

Again, it's not a dbt question but rather a docker question or an airflow question.

Can you see the logs in the airflow UI when using a DockerOperator? Yes, [see this how to blog post with screenshots](https://marclamberti.com/blog/how-to-use-dockeroperator-apache-airflow/).

Can you access logs from a docker container? Yes, Docker containers emit logs to `stdout` and `stderr` output streams (which you can see in airflow, since airflow picks this up). But logs are also stored in JSON files on the host machine in a folder `/var/lib/docker/containers/`. If you have any advanced needs, you can pick up those logs with a tool (or a simple BashOperator or PythonOperator) and do what you need with it.

3. > How would partial pipelines be run? (example: wanting to run only a part of the pipeline)

See answer 1, you would run your docker dbt image with the command

```sh
$ docker run my-dbt-image dbt run -m stg_customers
```