# dbt and google cloud composer PyPI dependency issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, dbt

I am currently running Google Cloud Composer with a Composer version `2.0.9` and airflow version `2.1.4`.  I am trying install the most recent version of dbt (`1.0.4` for core and `1.0.0` for the BigQuery plugin).  Because cloud composter images has specific packages installed, I am getting conflicting PyPI dependency issues.  When I try to fix one dependency another issue occurs.  Does anyone know the specific set of packages installed that would resolve this issue?  I have read the following posts by the community but I wanted to know if anyone has a solution for just using composer?

[How to run DBT in airflow without copying our repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890144/how-to-run-dbt-in-airflow-without-copying-our-repo/70134210#70134210)

[How to set up dbt with Google Cloud Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805961/how-to-set-up-dbt-with-google-cloud-composer)

Comment: Hi @dko512! If my answer helped please consider upvoting it. At the same time, since you were able to find the suitable versions, please accept your answer which will help the other community members too :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the behaviour you are seeing. Below are the dependency conflicts I saw in the Cloud Build logs. These conflicts are occurring between the `dbt-core` requirements and the pre-installed package requirements in Composer.

**Pre-installed package requirements**:

```py
hologram 0.0.14 has requirement jsonschema<3.2,>=3.0, but you have jsonschema 3.2.0. ##=> can be installed manually
flask 1.1.4 has requirement click<8.0,>=5.1, but you have click 8.1.2.
apache-airflow 2.1.4+composer has requirement markupsafe<2.0,>=1.1.1, but you have markupsafe 2.0.1.
looker-sdk 22.4.0 has requirement typing-extensions>=4.1.1, but you have typing-extensions 3.10.0.2.
```

**dbt-core requirements**:

```py
hologram 0.0.14 has requirement jsonschema<3.2,>=3.0, but you have jsonschema 3.2.0. ##=> can be installed manually
dbt-core 1.0.4 has requirement click<9,>=8, but you have click 7.1.2.
dbt-core 1.0.4 has requirement MarkupSafe==2.0.1, but you have markupsafe 1.1.1.
dbt-core 1.0.4 has requirement typing-extensions<3.11,>=3.7.4, but you have typing-extensions 4.1.1.
```

I tried downgrading the pre-installed packages, but subsequent package installations fail and it is [not recommended](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/troubleshooting-package-installation#:%7E:text=We%20do%20not%20recommend%20downgrading%20preinstalled%20packages.) as well.

Therefore, I would suggest using an external solution as stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805961/how-to-set-up-dbt-with-google-cloud-composer) you have linked. Quoting the workarounds given in @Ryan Yuan's answer here.

> 1. Using external services to run dbt jobs, e.g. Cloud Run.
> 2. Using Composer's [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/use-kubernetes-pod-operator)(updated Composer 2 link). My colleague has put up [a nice article on dbt discourse](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/running-dbt-in-composer-using-a-kubernetespodoperator/2590) here going through the setup process.
> 3. Ignoring Composer's Dependency conflicts by setting Composer's environmental variable IGNORE_PYPI_DEPENDENCY_CONFLICTS to True.
>    However, I don't recommend this as it may cause potential issues.
> 4. Creating a Python virtual environment in Composer and install the dbt packages.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Kabilan Mohanraj, the current version of dbt (1.0.4) and a more recent version of Composer has dependency issues (Composer version 2.0.9 and Airflow version 2.1.4).  Therefore an alternative solution is needed.  In my case, I played around and searched for a solution from other people in the community and found one person using a certain version of Composer and dbt that only had mimimal dependency issues.  However, as mentioned by @Kabilan Mohanraj, Google does not recommend downgrading preinstalled packages, so this would not be a viable solution for something in production.

create composer through gcloud to use an older version that is not available via the Composer UI

```
gcloud composer environments create my_airflow_dbt_example
--location us-central1
--image-version composer-1.17.9-airflow-2.1.4
```

requirements

```
dbt-bigquery==0.21.0
jsonschema==3.1.1
packaging==20.9
```

For this specific composer version, you are downgrading `jsonschema` from `3.2.0` to `3.1.1` and `packaging` from `21.3` to `20.9`